# Subclass NSArray in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I need to have a class, which has all methods of NSArray, which behave the same way, but 2 methods are modified.

I want to override these 2 methods in my custom class:

1) countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:

2) objectAtIndex:

After hours of research I don't see any reasonable way to do that, because:

- I don't want to use category, because not all NSArray instances should have the modified behaviour. (Plus that throws warnings)
- I don't want to re-write all initializers plus all arrayWith... methods + the primitive methods + implemented my own storage (because this functionality is already implemented in Cocoa, right? Why would I re-implement all the functionality of a class that is already there?)
- If I have my custom class inherit NSObject and use NSArray as storage in an ivar, then all NSArray's methods are not available when programming in Xcode (even if I can forward them to the NSArray ivar)
- I had some success overwriting the method implementations on demand by using method_setImplementation(...), but still can't figure out a way to have dynamically a class created at runtime, which then will have custom implementation of the 2 methods I mentioned.

Looking forward to your ideas! Thanks

Comment: Not a dupe, actually.   The other question doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: I think I'd just create a wrapper class.  Should be able to blindly forward most of the calls with resolveInstanceMethod, forwardingTargetForSelector, etc.

Comment: To answer OP's question;  you only need to override the primary methods to create a subclass.  The ones declared in the main @interface).  All other methods on the base class are implemented in terms of those methods. Override what you need beyond that for custom behavior and/or optimization.   A proxying wrapper is possible, but really really slow, by comparison.

Comment: @bbum -- You have to read the particulars for NSArray -- "Methods to override" includes a pretty daunting list of functions, depending on how you read it.

Comment: Not really -- you are only required to override `count` and `objectAtIndex:`.  All other methods on `NSArray` are implemented in terms of those two.   For `NSMutableArray`, adds 5 additional methods (that are straightforward array contents housekeeping).   If OP still wants a subclass, could still use NSMutableArray as the backing store, forwarding the primitive methods while adding any custom behaviors on top.

Comment: @bbum - you are actually wrong. I know very well what the Apple docs say on this topic. Do try to subclass NSArray and check how many of the methods you are used to use are actually inherited and you'll see what my problem is.

Comment: @Hot Licks - this won't provide you all the methods of NSArray in Xcode, ie. you won't be able to call for example initWithArray: on your wrapper object, unless you define this method in your wrapper class - and this for the whole list of NSArray methods. Give it a try and see what I mean

Comment: a useful article http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Comment: The initialization methods are not a part of the primitive methods for a variety of considered reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Mantra:*  If something is hard (or seems like it requires more code than is necessary), it is likely that your design is counter to the design principals of the iOS / OS X frameworks.  It may yield a better solution to revisit your design.

---

To answer the original question, if you want to subclass NSArray (or NSMutableArray), you need to implement the primitive methods, no more, no less.

The primitive methods are the methods declared in the `@interface` of the class itself.  I.e.:

```
@interface NSArray : NSObject
- (NSUInteger)count;
- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

And for NSMutableArray:

```
@interface NSMutableArray : NSArray
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject;
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeLastObject;
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;
@end
```

If you subclass NSMutableArray and implement the above 7 methods (the two from NSArray, too), you will have an NSMutableArray subclass that is compatible -- assuming your methods are correctly implemented -- with all APIs that consume mutable arrays.

This is because of the way class clusters are designed.  The public classes are abstract;  are never directly instantiated.   They provide a primitive interface that contains the class's core functionality and then concrete implementations of all the other non-primtive API (save for the initializers, see below) that are implemented in terms of the primitives.   Concrete, private, subclasses then override all the primitives and some of the non-primitives to provide optimal behaviors for specific configurations.

> I want to have an NSArray instance for a library I'm working on and I
>   want to have it working transparently for the users of my library. Ie.
>   for them should be no difference between using a normal NSArray and
>   the modified class I'll be providing. Ie. it's a storage concern,
>   which the end users should not be concerned with and the interface
>   should remain the same as NSArray - therefore loosing all init methods
>   is not really an option at that point.

The initialization methods *are not* a part of the primitive interface to `NSArray`.  You are adding a requirement above and beyond "make a class compatible with `NSArray` / `NSMutableArray`" as defined by the documentation.   Nothing wrong with that, just pointing it out.

The reason why this is the case is because it is exceptionally rare to subclass the collection classes to provide the kind of business logic you describe.   Collections are very generic in their behavior whereas such business logic that conditionalizes collection behavior would be  done in a class that manages the overall model layer object graph.

If you really want to do this, provide an implementation of whatever `init*` methods you want, calling through to your wrapped generic instance as needed.  There isn't anything so special about the implementations of the initializers that you are going to lose much in doing so.

No need to implement all of them, either.  Implement one or two and @throw a descriptive exception on the rest.

If you do decide to forward the ones that accept var-args, you can't directly because there are no va_list accepting methods.   Instead, you'll want to convert the va_list of arguments into a language array (i.e. `id[] foo = malloc(... * sizeof(id));`) and pass it to `initWithObjects:count:`.

Some other comments:

- What you are doing [provide full NS*Array interface in a subclass] seems hard because it is not a common pattern and the framework designers saw no need to create a design to support it.    Custom behaviors at the primitive collection levels are almost always better implemented at a higher level within the object graph.    *Almost* always.
- method_setImplementation() and dynamic class creation is academically interesting, but pretty much never a solution.   Obviously, mucking with the NSArray or NSMutableArray classes (or the concrete implementation classes) is going to blow up the rest of the frameworks that rely upon standard behavior.   Beyond that it, it is a pattern of dynamic OO composition that is not really intended to be used in Objective-C;   it'll be a pain in the ass to maintain.

Comment: Very well explained, +1. You could as well mention what the technical reason of the need of reimplementing primitive methods is (class cluster).

Comment: I must say that after several days of consideration I REALLY agree with what you just put together here. From years of experience with Apple I must've known better - with them there's only ONE right way. However you are spot-on on the fact that if it's extremely hard to do it in Cocoa then you're on the wrong way. I'm choosing to subclass, implement the primitive methods, implement 1 new own init method and overwrite the methods I want to modify. It's not 100% what I wanted, but it's close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing NSArray why not create a new class based on NSObject that contains an NSArray?

Then you can use all the functions of the NSArray and add your own methods that will do custom actions with it?

Or do you NEED an NSArray?

Comment: I want to have an NSArray instance for a library I'm working on and I want to have it working transparently for the users of my library. Ie. for them should be no difference between using a normal NSArray and the modified class I'll be providing. Ie. it's a storage concern, which the end users should not be concerned with and the interface should remain the same as NSArray - therefore loosing all init methods is not really an option at that point.