# How can I force objects of an array to conform to a specific protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, protocols

I want to allow for communication between different views.

I have two smaller views that sit on top of a bigger view, similar to iOS' video player, with some differences.  When I tap the bigger view I want to toggle the views appearance, hide or unhide.  I've got a protocol that all the views conform to.  I want to add the views to another class I'll call `HideViewsService`, which has an `NSArray` property.  Can I force the class that uses this `HideViewsService` class, and adds the views, to add only views that conform to this protocol?  Or even just `UIViews`?

Also, I'd like to call a method on the views that I know all have it, but I don't know how to get by the compiler.  Here is my `-hideAllViews` method:

```
-(void)hideAllViews
{
for(int i=0; i<self.viewArray.count; i++)
{
    id obj = [self.viewArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] == false)
    {
        return;
    }
    UIView *view = (UIView *)obj;
    if([view respondsToSelector:@selector(hide)])
    {
        [view hide]; // the compiler obviously doesn't like this
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!!  I'm still learning, so please tell me if there is a better way (not just easier, but better).

Comment: Never had to do this myself, but [here is a thread about sub-classing `NSArray`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13937777/620197).

Comment: what do you mean compiler doesn't like this? You are getting a warning?

Comment: Yes, an error.  It won't build if I tried to.  UIView does not have a public method named -hide.

Comment: are you using custom views, or have you declared a category? Your custom views have the method hide right?

Comment: Yeah, the custom views.

Comment: Don't subclass NSArray, just check and only add items that conform to the Protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ObjC does not have generics. Sometimes it would be nice if it did, but it doesn't. But the above design has several problems.

First, if `viewArray` is supposed to contain only `UIView` objects, then it is a programming error for it to contain anything else. It is not ok to just `return` if you find that it doesn't. If you're going to check this here, it should be `NSAssert()`. Similarly, if everything in `viewArray` should be respond to `hide`, you shouldn't just skip it if it doesn't. That's the source of many subtle bugs.

The better solution is to control addition of objects at the point of adding them to `HideViewsService` (though there are really better ways to do it anyway; we'll get to that).

```
@protocol XYZHideableView <NSObject>
- (void)hide;
@end

@interface XYZHideViewsService
- (void)addHideableView:(id<XYZHideableView>)view;
- (void)removeHideableView:(id<XYZHideableView>)view;
@end
```

Now, you don't need to worry about whether `viewArray` contains things that respond to `hide`.

That said, I'd generally do this with `NSNotificationCenter`. Hideable views should observe a notification like `XYZHideAllHideableViews`. When they set it, they should hide themselves. Then you don't need a `HideViewsService`. You just just need a `+[HideableView hideAllHideableViews]` class method.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compile without warnings you can just check if the object conforms to the protocol and then cast it to `id<Protocol>`:

```
if ([view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(Protocol)]) {
    id<Protocol> conformingView = (id<Protocol>)view;
    // or
    UIView<Protocol> *conformingView = (UIView<Protocol>*)view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the standard method that checks if an object conforms to a protocol:

```
 if ([object conformsToProtocol:Protocol]) {
    [array addObject:object];
}
```

and may I suggest using fast enumeration?

```
-(void)hideAllViews
{
for(CustomView *view in self.viewArray)
    {
     if([view respondsToSelector:@selector(hide)])
        {
        [view performSelector:@selector(hide)]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if([obj respondToSelector:selector){
  [obj performSelector:selector
}
```